# Неправильная сборка jade с помощью Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, jade

Есть такой таск, для преобразования jade в html, все правильно преобразовывается и копируется, но кроме самих файлов, дополнительно создается 2 директории с именами: templates.html (директория темплейтов) и Main.html (вложенная директория)

```
gulp.task('jade', function () {
    gulp.src('develop/templates/**/.*jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/templates'));
});
```

В чем ошибка? Предполагаю что в паттерне. По идеи должно взять все файлы с /develop/templates и положить в public/templates

Так же пробовал паттерн "develop/templates/**", который использую для JS, но поведение как и раньше, создается 2 директории

Comment: А так и должно быть... Если у Вас именно такое дерево (имею ввиду папка с файлами и в нее вложена ещё одно) и оно таким и будет, то можно попробовать src(['develop/templates/*.jade', develop/templates/main/*.jade']

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас такая структура то она будет повторятся, используйте например [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten), чтобы сделать ее плоской

Answer (score 0):

используйте Webpack для преобразования jade в функции (https://github.com/webpack/jade-loader) и подключайте их с помощью `require`, это избавит вас от необходимости возиться с расположением каталогов при сборке

Comment: Зря заминусовали - человек на самом деле пытается сэкономить ваше время. Использование webpack или browserify не противоречит использованию Gulp или любого другого автоматизатора сборки, но на самом деле сильно облегчает задачи, связанные со структурированием ресурсов и шаблонов, т.к. позволяет делать это прямо в коде проекта.